# Why cannot an array variable point anywhere else?

Tags: c

I am trying to understand why an array variable cannot point anywhere else?

Sample code:

```
 char s[] = "How big is it";
 const char *t = s;
```

This is the code,I create a sample array `s[]` and assign it a value "How big is it", now I create a character pointer array and assign it the value of s's address.

Now when I say something like this,the complier throws me an error:

```
 s=t;      ----> compiler error
```

Why is that? Is it because the string literal reference would get lost?

Comment: Read any good book about C programming. You cannot assign into an array (intuitively, because the `sizeof` of `s`  is much bigger than the `sizeof`  any pointer, which is always 8 on my machine). Ask yourself how the compiler should translate what you are trying to write!

Comment: "now I create a character pointer array" You don't. You create a character pointer. "why is that?? Is it because the string literal reference would get lost??" No, that's because you are not allowed to assign to an array.

Comment: It is a language design decision: arrays are not assignable. Also, arrays don't *point* to data, they *are* the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is an array name a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

`=` sign has two different meanings in C: *initialization* and *assignment*.

When you write `char s[]="How big is it";`, you *initialize* a new array with the characters of the string literal including the terminating null.

And the language simply does not allow *assignment* to an array. It would not make sense anyway because once defined, an array identify a memory location. You can then only assign to array elements or use functions that do that under the hood (memxx, strxx).